# how to create button hover effect like zbigz.com

Tags: jquery, css

I tried to search about this effect in stackover flow, but I have no clue, what developers call this kind of hover effect also no idea to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say that is `box-shadow` css property from css3 with `inset` applied:

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  background:#156a70;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:150px;
}
div:hover{
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px 5px rgba(135,255,249,1);
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me!!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just right click the button -> inspect element

And see this css:

```
#input-file-wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    top: 79px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(https://zbigz.com/img/upload-torrent-file-btn.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -0;
}

#input-file-wrapper:hover {
    background-position: 0 -43px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7h4zns5m/

If you take a look at the image you see that there are 3 different buttons, they just change the `background-position` to have another button image. That way it looks like it pops out ;)